# Handle Number Input in Firefox via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, firefox

I'm running into a strange issue in Firefox that I hope someone can explain to me. I have an AngularJS controller with a method that is tied to `ng-change` on a variety of input controls in a form, including one that is marked as a `number` input. The logic of this method is that if any one of the bound scope variables is set properly, to set another scope variable to true. This is basically an attempt at form validation where any one (or more) of the inputs is required.

Example:

```
app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.num = 0;
  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.valid = false;

  $scope.inputChange = function() {
    console.log('Input changed');
    $scope.valid = ($scope.num > 0) || ($scope.name.length > 0);
  }
});
```

And form:

```
<form name="numberTest" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="test">
      <input ng-model="name" name="name" type="text" ng-change="inputChange()"/>
      <input type="number" ng-model="num" name="n" id="n" ng-change="inputChange()"/>
      <input type="button" value="Go" ng-disabled="!valid"/>
</form>
```

This all works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox this `ng-change` handler is fired when non-numeric text is entered in the numeric input and the textbox itself does get this bogus data in it although the model is not updated. This leads to a confusing state where there is invalid data in the num textbox that is not bound to the AngularJS model but the user can click the button. Chrome does not present this problem as it does not render the non-numeric data in the input control.

How can I detect (and handle) this scenario? The input control is displaying text that is invalid and not bound to the binding model.

I am certainly open to alternative implementations to achieve this same effect. AngularJS version is 1.3.0.

Example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I9k65tuJcXUDQJfpRO2B?p=preview) to run in Firefox to see the "bad" behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up discovering the [`$valid`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) attribute of these number inputs, and that seemingly satisfies my needs:

- Returns true if empty
- Returns false if non-numeric data is in the control

So, my updated button:

```
<input type="button" value="Go" ng-disabled="!valid || !numberTest.n.$valid"/>
```